# Aggregating individual-level correlations to make an aggregate-level claim

Tags: regression, correlation, estimation, aggregation

I have a correlation between X and Y for different groups (they are states in the US, fwiw):

[image]

I'd like to make some claim about the *aggregate correlation*: something like "Overall, as X increases, Y decreases." *Prima facie* this seems like a reasonable claim to make as most of the individual correlations are downward-sloping.

However, I can't simply aggregate and regress all of the points: this would be committing the ecological fallacy, and give me an overestimate of the overall effect:

[image]

How can I perform some meaningful and "kosher" statistical analysis here? There must be something I can meaningfully conclude. I thought of using an arithmetic mean of each individual regression line, or running the regression while controlling for state. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289139/fit-individual-level-model-on-aggregate-level-target-data) seems to be related, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why does state matter at all? If you have individual level data, then simply use a regression model. Judging by the number of points, you could easily adjust for each state as well as its interaction with $X$ and make inferences accordingly.

Comment: @AdamO, do you mean the functional form $$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 State$$ where $State$ is a dummy variable? Is it necessary to interact with X?

Comment: After all, if I interact with State to get the functional form $$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 State + \beta_3 State * X$$, I recover the individual regressions.

Comment: Picking up on AdamO's comment, as I understand his suggestion it would conform with the first functional form in your first response. If you're running a linear regression using OLS, then the F-statistics would provide information about the strength of the association but be uninformative wrt the sign of the relationship. Running t-tests for each parameter would provide that more granular information. The magnitude and sign of *t* for *X* would give you the answer you seek.

Comment: @LieuZhengHong yes I do mean state as a dummy variable. Add the interaction, and it is 102 fixed effects in the model. But if the graphs are correct, I see there are several hundred if not thousand individual observations per state.